# Dart: how to resolve a host name

Tags: networking, dart

I'm trying to find a method to resolve a host name to an ip address using dart.

I've look through the apis and I can't find a method.

e.g.

InternetAddress addr = resolve('www.google.com.au')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [InternetAddress.lookup](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-io/InternetAddress/lookup.html) in `dart:io`.

```dart
InternetAddress addr = InternetAddress.lookup('www.google.com.au');
```